# Proper way to use stat() function to access m_time

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming

My program takes user input and checks to see if a file was modified with in a minutes than the user input. I am trying to get the last modified time of the file using the stat() function as follows:

Note: op_mmin is the user input in minutes

```
struct stat buf;    
stat(sub_directory, &buf);

if((time(NULL) - buf.st_mtime) < atoi(op_mmin) * 60) // if the file was modified in less time ago than specified
{
    printf("%d\n", buf.st_mtime); // this print statement simply is used to check what the st_mtime is.
    printf("%s\n", full_path); // print the full path of the file
}
```

My code currently prints seemingly random negative numbers like `-1036294304` and `-367577248`. I just created the files it is searching so `time(NULL) - buf.st_mtime` should be relatively small.

Comment: `buf.st_mtime` is `time_t`, but you're printing it as `int` (with `%d` format). Use `%lld` and explicitly cast it to `long long`, just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll better clear with `memset(&buf,0,sizeof(buf));` before calling `stat` and you should check that [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) succeeded... so at least:

```
struct stat buf;
memset (&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
if (stat (sub_directory, &buf)) 
   { perror(sub_directory); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>(the clearing by `memset` is in principle useless; in practice, initializing or clearing every local variable is so helpful for debugging purposes & to have more reproducible behavior that I am always doing that; BTW in that precise case the compiler would optimize by inlining the call to `memset`, and the time to clear `buf` is negligible w.r.t. the call to *any* syscall, here `stat`)</sup>

Then you should cast `time_t` difference  to some `long` at least:

```
if((long)(time(NULL) - buf.st_mtime) < atol(op_mmin) * 60) {
  printf("mtime=%ld, subdir=%s\n", (long) buf.st_mtime, sub_directory); 
}
```

You should spend a day or two reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), and before using any [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) you should carefully read its documentation (and care about its failure).

Perhaps [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could also be useful (at least to understand what syscalls your program is doing).

Of course, you'll better compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  (many warnings & debug info) and use the `gdb`  debugger (in which you might have set a breakpoint before the `stat`  and run some instructions `step` by step).

BTW, if on Linux (specifically) with local file systems (Ext4, BTRFS, ...) you might be interested by [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities.

Comment: I don't see the need to zero the struct before calling `stat`, as it will be filled anyway by the function (of course if `stat` returns 0)

Comment: @ringø: in theory you are right; in practice, it is a good habit to have; I added a small paragraph explaining that.